# Pulumi- C# - output variable

Tags: c#, pulumi, pulumi-azure

I am trying to provision resource group with below class. Calling it from the stack class but facing some issue with the output variable.

```
class GenerateResourceGroup
{
    public GenerateResourceGroup(Input<string> location, Input<string> rgName, Dictionary<string, string> tags)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(location);
        Console.WriteLine(rgName);
        var config = new Pulumi.Config();
        var resourceGroup = new Pulumi.AzureNative.Resources.ResourceGroup("resourceGroup", new Pulumi.AzureNative.Resources.ResourceGroupArgs
        {
            Location = location,
            ResourceGroupName = rgName,
            Tags = tags,
        });
        resourceGroupName = resourceGroup.Name;
    }
    [Output]
    public Output<string> resourceGroupName { get; }
}
```

Error: Even I tried to utilize apply but still getting error.

> Pulumi.Input`1[System.String] Pulumi.Input`1[System.String]
> Calling [ToString] on an [Output] is not supported.
> To get the value of an Output as an Output consider:
> 1. o.Apply(v => $"prefix{v}suffix")
> 2. Output.Format($"prefix{hostname}suffix");
> See https://pulumi.io/help/outputs for more details.

Comment: Your code looks fine expect for `Console.WriteLine` that prints `Input<string>` directly. If you just remove those console statements, does the rest work for you?

Comment: i removed the console.writeline, but getting error  Detail="invocation of azure-native:authorization:getClientConfig returned an error: getting authenticated object ID: Error parsing json result from the Azure CLI: Error retrieving running Azure CLI: WARNING: This command or command group has been migrated to Microsoft Graph API. Please carefully review all breaking changes introduced during this migration: https://learn.microsoft.com/cli/azure/microsoft-graph-migration")

Answer (score 0):

It was an issue with the cli.. i uninstalled the latest version of CLI and installed old version 2.33.1. That has solved the problem. It's all bcoz underlying api due to the depreciation of the API..  learn.microsoft.com/cli/azure/microsoft-graph-migration